# KafkaStorageException: Disk error when trying to access log file on the disk

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Can anyone let me know what causes the error

> WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition my-example-topic1-1 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Disk error when trying to access log file on the disk.. Going to request metadata update now"

I am running a 3 broker Kafka setup on the windows environment, I have created 2 TOPICs with 5 partitions each, I am using 2 producer instances. One for each TOPIC and I am using a single Consumer instance to consume from both of these TOPICs. The setup worked fine for some time. Then one of the Producer and the Consumer stopped functioning, the following messages were printed on the Producer and Consumer Console,

my-example-topic1 & my-example-topic2 are the 2 TOPICs.

Producer Console:

> 74394 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 74494 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 74595 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 74697 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 74798 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 74900 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 75001 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]

Consumer Console:

> 17533 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 17636 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 17738 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 17840 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 17943 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 18044 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 18147 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 18248 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]
> 18350 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer1-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [my-example-topic1-1]

Comment: Since you mentioned that the setup stopped working after some time, there is a chance of disk getting full. Could you verify the disk space on your both brokers corresponding to kafka log dir

Comment: The disk space is not full, i Have verified the space on all 3 of my brokers